# Splitting audio tracks with incorrect length - FFMPEG

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

Version: com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2

I have an audio file with length 43 seconds. And I wrote an algorithm to split at each 10 seconds mark where a word ends (For this I used IBM Watson to get ending timestamp). So cropping duration is always around 10 seconds to 11 seconds. Of course except the 5th one. I have printed my commands so that you will understand my use-case better.

```
System.out: Split Command: -y -i /storage/emulated/0/AudioClipsForSpeakerRecognition/merge.wav -ss 00:00:00.000 -codec copy -t 00:00:10.010 /storage/emulated/0/AudioClipsForSpeakerRecognition/segment_1.wav

System.out: Split Command: -y -i /storage/emulated/0/AudioClipsForSpeakerRecognition/merge.wav -ss 00:00:10.010 -codec copy -t 00:00:21.090 /storage/emulated/0/AudioClipsForSpeakerRecognition/segment_2.wav

System.out: Split Command: -y -i /storage/emulated/0/AudioClipsForSpeakerRecognition/merge.wav -ss 00:00:21.090 -codec copy -t 00:00:30.480 /storage/emulated/0/AudioClipsForSpeakerRecognition/segment_3.wav

System.out: Split Command: -y -i /storage/emulated/0/AudioClipsForSpeakerRecognition/merge.wav -ss 00:00:30.480 -codec copy -t 00:00:40.120 /storage/emulated/0/AudioClipsForSpeakerRecognition/segment_4.wav

System.out: Split Command: -y -i /storage/emulated/0/AudioClipsForSpeakerRecognition/merge.wav -ss 00:00:40.120 -codec copy -t 00:00:43.000 /storage/emulated/0/AudioClipsForSpeakerRecognition/segment_5.wav
```

However when playing all cropped audio files I noticed segment_1 is about 10 seconds and segment_2 is about 20 seconds etc. Therefore some of the audio parts belong to segment_1 also available in segment 2 etc etc. Why is this happening?

Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-t` represents duration. Use `-to` instead.